# How do I post a multipart request with request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, multipartform-data

The title simply says it. I can not figure out how to send a a couple of fields vial multipart.

I understand that there is an implementation with https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data

I have all my fields available and would just to post it as multipart and work with the async result...

For any examples better or for me more clearer than then the one on the authors github's page (https://github.com/mikeal/request) would be fantastic...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the following at the end of [node-form-data](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data)?

"In order to submit this form to a web application, you can use node's http client interface:"

```
var http = require('http');

var request = http.request({
  method: 'post',
  host: 'example.org',
  path: '/upload',
  headers: form.getHeaders()
});

form.pipe(request);

request.on('response', function(res) {
  // work with the result here
  console.log(res.statusCode);
});
```

It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like mentioned in my question I would like to use the request module because my component relies on that and I would need to do some more advanced things

Comment: Works the same with request.js ... form.pipe did the trick as well as form.getHeaders() thanks for the heads up...